# How to automate iPhone jail break by writing Shell or any scripts?

Tags: ios, iphone, shell, jailbreak, cydia

Am trying to jail break the iOS devices automatically. We are working on Jail broken devices and we want to jail break 100's of iOS device. It is not possible to do manual jail break the bunch of devices and install the required packages (`Cydia`).

I don't have experience on any Scripting languages. If anyone already tried this before please share your experience and that would be guide me to do this. Am welcoming your suggestions and ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. First, you need to jailbreak them - it requires connecting them to your PC through USB and using jailbreak tools which do not support any automation (at least the recent ones). Then you need to manually install afc2 daemon to gain access to root folder - without it you can't even copy any deb packages on your device because filesystem is still jailed. Only then you can copy a bunch of deb packages to cydia auto install folder but still need to manually reboot devices to install them.

To do any kind of automation you need at least OpenSSH installed which is not installed by default. So I don't think you can do much here.

Comment: To add to this, most recent jailbreaks require human intervention on the device to open an injected app.

Comment: @radj, not all of them. TaiG, for example, is the simplest of all. Click one button on your PC and after reboot device will be jailbroken. Still, no afc2d is installed by default.